# How to display data from jquery api call for stock price

Tags: jquery, api, stock

I am trying to display the end of day (eod) stock price for a share (Lloyds Bank) for a school project.

I have an account with marketstack.com who provide the API. The URL request works well, but I would really love some help helping me display this on a page.

The URL is: https://api.marketstack.com/v1/tickers/LLOY.XLON/eod/latest?access_key=YOUR_API_KEY

(I've removed my API key).

This returns the following:

```
{"open":42.4,"high":43.575,"low":42.195,"close":43.395,"volume":139808684.0,"adj_high":null,"adj_low":null,"adj_close":43.395,"adj_open":null,"adj_volume":null,"split_factor":1.0,"dividend":0.0,"symbol":"LLOY.XLON","exchange":"XLON","date":"2022-06-24T00:00:00+0000"}
```

Marketstack have provided the following example jQuery code as a demo.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.marketstack.com/v1/tickers/aapl/eod',
  data: {
    access_key: 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(apiResponse) {
    if (Array.isArray(apiResponse['data'])) {
      apiResponse['data'].forEach(stockData => {
            console.log(`Ticker ${stockData['symbol']}`,
                `has a day high of ${stockData['high']},
                `on ${stockData['date']}`);
      });
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

How do I make the API call, get the 'close' value and get it as a var object so I can display in on my page?

Thank you for your help - I hope to help others with their code someday!

---

Updated code below:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.marketstack.com/v1/tickers/NWG.XLON/eod/latest',
  data: {
  access_key: 'b391c31dfc8a648bd50b9b0befc8bec7'},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(apiResponse)
  {if (Array.isArray(apiResponse['data'])) {
  apiResponse['data'].forEach(stockData => {
   console.log(`Ticker ${stockData.symbol}, has a day high of ${stockData.high}, on ${stockData.date}`);
  });
}
}
});
</script>
```

Removed the `{if (Array.isArray` block

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.marketstack.com/v1/tickers/NWG.XLON/eod/latest',
  data: {
  access_key: 'b391c31dfc8a648bd50b9b0befc8bec7'},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(apiResponse)
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory. Would you mind helping me put the ajax request together? It makes sense to me in the URL but struggling with it broken down in jquery/ajax form.

Comment: Fab. I've added your line of code to the success function. I'm getting an error in the console log. Do i need the forEach statement or is that unnecessary?

Comment: I added an answer below demontrating the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct. The issue you have is that your syntax around the template literal is incorrect. You have used too many `` ` `` characters. It's clearer to see this if you keep the literal on a single line.

```js
// mock response:
let apiResponse = {"pagination":{"limit":100,"offset":0,"count":1,"total":1},"data":[{"open":42.4,"high":43.575,"low":42.195,"close":43.395,"volume":139808684.0,"adj_high":null,"adj_low":null,"adj_close":43.395,"adj_open":null,"adj_volume":null,"split_factor":1.0,"dividend":0.0,"symbol":"LLOY.XLON","exchange":"XLON","date":"2022-06-24T00:00:00+0000"}]}

// inside AJAX succes handler:
if (Array.isArray(apiResponse['data'])) {
  apiResponse['data'].forEach(stockData => {
    console.log(`Ticker ${stockData.symbol}, has a day high of ${stockData.high}, on ${stockData.date}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm on it now, thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: Thanks Rory - apologies but I'm not seeing anything in the console.

Comment: Not even any errors? There should be an entry in the network tab of the console to monitor the request being made via AJAX. If you're not even seeing this then the request isn't happening, and you would need to debug to figure out why that is.

Comment: I just noticed the update to the question - remove the `if (Array.isArray(...` block, just as a test

Comment: Hi Rory, I can't work it out - there's nothing in the console. When I remove the `if (Array.isArray(...` block, I get an uncaught syntax error - but have removed it correctly - showed what I did above.

Comment: I've removed the block and got the API response coming through in the console now When I add the block to go inside the AJAX success handler, i see nothing in the console

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, I meant to remove the Array.array calls, not the entire block. Your code should look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3Lm6jfxv/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245981/discussion-between-t-sproull-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: Sorry Rory - the JSfiddle returns an error... still struggling! I've got the array, just need to get the 'close' data as a var

Comment: The jsFiddle isn't functional... is was just somewhere you can copy the code from. However, I added a jQuery reference so it executes. The problem is becuase the response from the AJAX request doesn't match the example you have in the question. There's not an array, just a single StockItem, so the code should look like this for that case: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3Lm6jfxv/1/

Comment: Rory - thank you! Got it working now. You're a star, I'm very grateful.